# How to use Domain Transform Edge-Preserving technique for Image Enhancement in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filter, dns, transform, edge-detection

I am interested in using this Domain Transform Edge-Preserving Video filtering technique (http://inf.ufrgs.br/~eslgastal/DomainTransform/ - source code available there) for image enhancement in Matlab (2015a).

At around 3:12 on a 5-minute video (on the site linked above), they perform detail enhancement. I'm not sure how to use the filtered image to sharpen/deblur my original image.

I usually use:

```
H = padarray(2,[2 2]) - fspecial('gaussian' ,[5 5],2);
sharpened = imfilter(I,H);
```

to sharpen images, but I can't use imfilter with the filtered image from the edge-preserving technique (I've been testing with the normalized convolution filter from the source code) that I'm interested in.

Can anyone advise me on what I can do to make use of this filtered image for sharpening/deblurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't dive too deep into this specific implementation of an edge-preserving filter, but detail enhancement looks very much like unsharp masking.  The equation you provided embeds the subtraction into a single filter but a typical implementation looks more like this:

```
I_lpf = imfilter(I,fspecial('gaussian',[5 5],2);
I_sharpened = I + boost_factor*(I - I_lpf);
```

If you replace the linear convolution in the `imfilter` command with an edge preserving low pass filtered image you will get detail enhancement.

Comment: (Sorry it's all bunched up. New to the site and don't know how to get it spaced out as I have it during input)

Okay, so when I run the normalized convolution process from the edge-preserving technique on an input image (say F), I produce an image "F_nc"

So when you say to replace the linear convolution in the imfilter command, do you mean to write:

I_lpf = imfilter(F,F_nc, [5 5], 2);

? And the rest would perform the detail enhancement?
By the way, boost_factor is an unrecognised function/variable for me. Unless it's value is up to me to determine?

Comment: I'm suggesting you replace `I_lpf = imfilter(I,...` with `I_lpf = myChoiceOfEdgePreservingLowpassFilter(I , ... )`.  I'm not familiar enough the specific method you're referencing to confirm if `F_nc` is the low pass filter output, but if that's the case then just substitute `F_nc` for `I_lpf` in the above.

Comment: `boost_factor` is just a scalar that controls the strength of the enhancement.  If you set it to zero you get your original image back. If you set it to a large number you get a lot of enhancement.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and consideration. I am getting understandable results now. (Instead of plain black or white images, or errors, I'm getting sharper images, though with increased noise now ha ha but I expected that to happen).